# Web service that returns intermediate results

Tags: web-services, asynchronous, messaging, synchronous

What would be the best way to implement a Web Service that returns some intermediate results before the actual result of the call is returned (e.g., a status for a long lasting transaction)?

What would be the best way if the Web Service call has to be synchronous?